# how do you use ActiveX in XAML under WinRT?

Tags: windows-runtime, activex, winrt-xaml

I am attempting to use the RDP control in a WinRT XAML app. The MS sample is a JS contraption that seems to use the ActiveX component. How can you incorporate an ActiveX control into a XAML app ?

Answer (score 1):

On page 5 in [Migrating your Build app to Windows 8 Consumer Preview whitepaper](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=242888) you can find the section:

**ActiveX object removal in Windows Store apps with JavaScript**

> Previously, it was possible to instantiate a small set of ActiveX
> objects.
>
> These included some XML-related ActiveX objects. Ability to
> instantiate these has been removed.